# Random Forest in-bag and node dimensions

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, random-forest

I have to do a random forest classifier for an exercise and the exercise specifically says for the parameters,  and I quote from my language

> in-bag percentage: 25% 50% 85%
>
> Number of dimensions in one node: 10%, 50%, 80%

I use scikit-learn for the classifier and I don't know which are the parameters from the class to set the in-bag percentage and the number of dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the number of dimension using `max_features` parameter. Something like:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(max_features=.1)
```

Unfortunately, `RandomForestClassifier` doesn't *yet* support subsampling (i.e. in-bag percentage). However this feature has been [added](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/14682) in current development branch of sklearn, so will be available in future.

A good workaround for now is to use `BaggingClassifier`: it have a `max_samples` parameter for subsampling, and it can be turned into `RandomForestClassifier` using `DecisionTreeClassifier` as base.

```
base = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_features=.1)    
rf = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator=base, max_samples=.25)
```

Note that `BaggingClassifier` also have a `max_features` parameter, but that works differently than Random Forest does.